# Multiprocessing in tornado

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, tornado

I want to have two non-blocking processes running synchronously, the one is a while True loop which caches data every minute, and the second one is a code such below:

```
def create_and_start_app():
    app = Application([
        ('/dashboard', Dashboard)
    ],
    debug=RuntimeConfig.DEBUG_MODE)
    http_server = HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(RuntimeConfig.APP_PORT)
    print(f'Listening on http:/{RuntimeConfig.APP_HOST}:{RuntimeConfig.APP_PORT}')
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

I tried `IOLoop.current.spawn_call_back` approach and also `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` but it seems I didn't get the point of documentation because every approach I test, blocks with while True in caching method and program doesn't execute next process. Thank you if you show me a sample code which fits into this case.

Comment: How are you pausing the `while` loop? Are you using `time.sleep`?

Comment: yes, I use time.sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.sleep` is a blocking function. It suspends the whole thread, therefore it's not ideal to use in an async program. You ought to use an asynchronous equivalent of it (such as [`tornado.gen.sleep`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.sleep) or [`asyncio.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping) which will only suspend the coroutine, not the whole thread.

Example:

```
from tornado import gen

async def my_coroutine():
    while True:
        # do somehting ...
        await gen.sleep(5 * 60) # pause while loop for 5 minutes
```